# Cut of word from a string and store result to variable

Tags: macos, bash, shell, cut

How can i cut first word from a string, and then result store to variable?

So in the input i have String with 5 words.

Output will be 4 words without first one and must be stored in variable.

Already tried `echo "First Second Third Fourth Fifth" | cut -d " " -f2-` but i can't store result in variable.

Also i don't wont to see result of executing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `command substitution` like this:

```
result=$(echo "First Second Third Fourth Fifth" | cut -d " " -f2-)

echo "$result"
```

OR using pure BASH:

```
s="First Second Third Fourth Fifth"
echo "${s#* }"
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Second Third Fourth Fifth
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would prefer myself, would be to have the string in a text file, and then you can do this:-

```
read first second third fourth fifth < file
```

Then you can simply use:-

```
echo "${first}"
etc
```

Read is awesome. :D